# react-native-map image source not update on android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-maps

I use react-native-map for to display different merchants on my card and when I press one of the markers, a modal appears with the detail (like on the screenshot) :

[image]

Normally, when I press the marker, the icon changes to represent the selection.
Here is the code in relation:

```
{ this.state.markerIcons ?  Object.keys(this.state.markers).map((marker, key) =>{ 
        if (!this.state.markers[marker].shouldShow) return
         console.log('My Selected marker : ', this.state.selectedMarker  && marker == this.state.selectedMarker.key);
        return (  
          <CustomMarkers
              key={marker}
              coordinate={this.state.markers[marker].coordinate}
              onPress={()=>this.setState({selectedMarker:this.state.markers[marker]})}
          >
           <Image source={
            this.state.selectedMarker  && marker == this.state.selectedMarker.key ?
             require('../images/mapmarker/default.png')
             :
             icons[this.state.markerIcons[this.state.markers[marker].category].icon]
            } 
             />
          </CustomMarkers>
        )})
        : <View></View>
      }
```

it works very well on ios but the icon does not change on android ??
An idea ??